# What is the purpose of a dishwasher elbow?

Tags: plumbing

I am installing a dishwasher that has a 3/4-inch threaded male connection for the water line. The instructions say to buy a dishwasher elbow to connect to this piece, then connect the other side of the elbow to a standard 3/8-inch compression sink hose.

Is there any reason why I couldn't instead connect a 3/4-inch female hose directly to the dishwasher?

Another way of asking this question is: What is the purpose of a dishwasher elbow? Other than adapting a standard 3/8-inch sink hose to a larger dishwasher water inlet, is there a reason you need to have the elbow?

Comment: an elbow would change the direction of the water connection ... it would also allow the connection to have the ability to swivel in a vertical direction

Answer (score 3):

Typically there is very little clearance behind the dishwasher and the back of the cabinet.

A hose attached directly to the inlet might have to be bent and kinked in order to fit.  That would not be good.  The elbow allows the supply line to run parallel to the back of the dishwasher without taking up much room.

As for the ¾" versus ⅜" connectors, again typically the nearby sink would have a shutoff valve with a ⅜" connector, so a standard ⅜" connecting hose would be the obvious thing to use.

It doesn't mean that one *can't* use other types of hoses, only that one would have to go out of their way to need to.

Comment: Thanks; that makes sense. I guess it's mostly an access/convenience thing, then. Makes me wonder why the manufacturers don't just make them with a connection that would be easy to access and use a standard hose. They want another part to sell you, I suppose.